# haml error messages: expecting keyword_end, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a tiny haml file that's causing all sorts of irrational error messages. The file is this:

```
%h1 Collaborator List for Private Wiki "#{@wiki.title}"
- for @wiki.relationships.each do |r|
  - if !r.created_creator do
    %h3 Users.email.where(relationship=r)
```

The error messages are:

```
/home/vagrant/code/blocipedia/app/views/wikis/collaborator_list.html.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end ...:Util.html_safe(_erbout);ensure;@haml_buffer = @haml_buffer.... ... ^ /home/vagrant/code/blocipedia/app/views/wikis/collaborator_list.html.haml:4: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting :: or '[' or '.' /home/vagrant/code/blocipedia/app/views/wikis/collaborator_list.html.haml:7: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

I imagine the problem has to do with nesting, but I can't see it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Completely randomly, you should consider using select or reject here: #wiki.relationships.select { |r| !r.created_creator }.each or #wiki.relationships.reject { |r| r.created_creator }.each to eliminate the if statement. (Forgive the #s, the validator doesn't like the at-signs.)

Comment: Thanks! I have several places where I can use this advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message typically means that you've missed a `do` clause for an iterator. In your case, your Ruby clauses in the HAML are invalid, specifically using both a `for` and an enumerator (`#each`), and `do` following the `if`.

```
%h1 Collaborator List for Private Wiki "#{@wiki.title}"
- @wiki.relationships.each do |r|
  - if !r.created_creator
    %h3 Users.email.where(relationship=r)
```

You can make this a bit nicer, though:

```
%h1 Collaborator List for Private Wiki "#{@wiki.title}"
- @wiki.relationships.reject(&:created_creator).each do |r|
  %h3 Users.email.where(relationship=r)
```

This first rejects all entries from the relationships where `r.created_creator` evaluates to a truthy value, then iterates over the remaining values, giving you both your selection criteria and your iteration.

Comment: wouldn't you need a `=` after %h3?

Comment: Probably, but I figured the OP would figure that out :)